# bounded sets $ B\in X/M$ where $X$ is a normed vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, $ M\le X$ a linear subspace. Let $ X/M$ with the quotient norm.
Prove that $ B \subset X/M$ is bounded iff there exist a bounded set $A\subset X$ such that $ B\subset [A]$.

If there exist $A$ such that $ ||a|| < M$ $\forall a\in A$ then given $\bar b\in B \subset [A]$, where $ b \in X$, since $ ||\bar b||=inf_{m\in M}||{b+m}||$ it's obvious that for some fixed $m_0\in M$,  $||\bar b|| \le || b+m_0 || \ le ||b||+ ||m_0|| \le M+ ||m_0||$ , thus $B$ is bounded by $M+||m_0||$ in norm.

For the other side I'm a little confused :/

Comment: $B$ is bounded if and only if it is contained in a multiple of the _open_ unit ball in $X/M$.

Comment: You are right, and again the open unit mall in $X/M$ is the image of the unit open ball in $X$ Thanks!